# oci.dll could not be located in dynamic link library

Tags: vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g, oracle-call-interface

I am unsure why all of the sudden i am getting this error every time i compile and run my VB.net program running Oracle 10g. It ran fine many times but all of the sudden keeps saying this now.

http://i55.tinypic.com/24vqhc0.jpg

It happens on this line:

```
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=" & _
              "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & dbHost & ")(PORT=" & dbPort & ")))" & _
              "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" & dbServiceName & ")));" & _
              "User Id=" & dbUserId & ";Password=" & dbPassword & ";")

    Try
        myConnection.Open()
```

Once it gets to the myConnection.Open() is when it displays that error box. Like i said, i used to work just fine.

I'm not sure what i need to do in order to correct this so any help would be great!

David

Comment: Did you solved the issue completely, I've same issue with me,, what shall I do!! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the Oracle data provider.  It is best to reinstall it.